# Add a Fee / Surcharge on Cart/Order amount over 200$

Tags: orders, cart

How can i add a fee / surcharge on cart amount over 200$?
Or how can i add shipping fee for orders over 200$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table rates for achieving this. You can try https://elgentos.nl/tablerates/ and the upload the generated csv to your shop.

Comment: In addition, if you have other requirements or want more flexibility, there is [Fooman Surcharge](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/surcharge-by-fooman.html).